# Scully install fails with Puppeteer renderer

Tags: scully

Following Scully install directions:
`ng add @scullyio/init`
for a basic Angular 14 application and getting:

```
TypeError: entry.message.split is not a function
    at MapSubscriber.project (...\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\logger\indent.js:35:58)  
    at MapSubscriber._next (...\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\map.js:49:35)  
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (...\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:66:18)  
    at Subject.next (...\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subject.js:60:25)  
    at IndentLogger.log (...\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\logger\logger.js:83:23)  
    at IndentLogger.error (...\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\logger\logger.js:98:21)  
    at ...\node_modules\@scullyio\init\src\ng-add\index.js:89:24  
    at MergeMapSubscriber.project (...\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\src\rules\call.js:75:24)  
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (...\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:67:27)  
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (...\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:57:18)
```

node @ 16.17.0
npm @ 8.19.1
And Angular project has all dependencies up to date as of posting.

Not sure what I can be doing wrong with a single ng command, but can anyone help me resolve this error?  There's a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/scullyio/scully/issues/15950) from June with this exact error that just states to update Angular and npm.  This was my first attempt to use Scully, and I'm not filled with confidence.

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Comment: I have not.  I just tried again with the same result (this time with @scullyio/init v2.1.41).